# Why is the ratio of arc lengths equal to the ratio of angular measures in circles.

Tags: geometry

I want to know for two circles why the ratio of arc length is equal to the ratio of the two central angles in geometry. It must have something to do with the concept of similarity in geometry. I have scoured the Internet looking answers but only found the ratio of circumferences to the ratio of their diameter.

If my question seems crude it is because I have never posted a question before.

Comment: Take two identical wedges and place them next to each other along a common edge. The angle doubles and so does the arc length. These quantities are proportional to each other.

Comment: As you say, it is exactly because of similarity. A similarity preserves angles, and preserves straightness, but it multiplies lengths (of line segments and of circular arcs and of any path whatsoever) by a constant.

Comment: Isn't the measure of an angle *defined* to be the arc length that the angle subtends on a circle of unit radius?

Comment: The main reason, mathematically, is  that arc lengths on the unit circle *are* the measures of the central angles (in radians).

Comment: What I am interested in are the "ratio" of arc lengths equal to the "ratio" of angle measures. It are the ratios that concern me. Thanks

Comment: sorry, but my question doesn't assume equal radii

Answer (score 3):

It is a basic feature of euclidean geometry, not present in spherical or hyperbolical geometry, that we have available a large family of "special" maps $T_{O,\rho}\,$, called *homotheties*. These maps are stretching the base space ${\mathbb E}^2$ linearly from a given center $O$ with a given factor $\rho>0$ in the obvious way. They have the property that all distances $|PQ|$ between points $P$, $Q\in{\mathbb E}^2$ are multiplied by $\rho$, and they map circles onto circles. Since lengths of curves are defined via lengths of inscribed polygons and a limiting process it follows that lengths of curves are multiplied by $\rho$ as well. This then implies that the lengths of corresponding arcs on concentric circles behave in the expected way.

Now the measure $\alpha$ of an angle is defined by the length of the corresponding arc on the unit circle. In this way the length of the corresponding arc on a concentric circle of radius $r$ becomes $r\,\alpha$. Furthermore it is easy to see that similarities preserve angles.

Answer (score 1):

The arc length of a circle with radius $r$ is $2r\pi$. The full circle has a central angel of $\varphi=2\pi$. Therefore, given a central angel $\varphi$, you can calculate the arc length by $r\varphi$. So the following statements hold:

- For a fixed central angel $\varphi$, the arc length $r\varphi$ is proportional to the radius $r$.
- For a fixed radius $r$, the arc length $r\varphi$ is proportional to the central angel $\varphi$.